# Locust result summary. How to understand Avg, Min and Max?

Tags: locust

I use Locust, a load testing framework, and the following is the summary of a test result.

```
Name                                                          # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /sample                                                    10000     0(0.00%)      97      56     349  |      96  761.90
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                          10000     0(0.00%)                                     761.90
```

I guess that req/s means 761.90 requests are processed in 1 second. How about Avg, Min, Max and Median? How can I read these columns?.

This perfomance test tooks about 15 sec. I set min_wait = 0 max_wait = 0.

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at the source](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/locust/stats.py), it appears to refer to the response time

Comment: Thanks. I found "avg_response_time   = float(self.total_response_time) / self.num_requests". My case is 97ms = total_response_time / 10,000. total_response_time = 970,000ms. It's about 16min. It did not make sense so I posted this question. But now I think I understand it. The total_response_time is just the total. The requests are sent in parallel. It does not matter the time of the whole processing time, it's about 15sec.